# Migrate TimeZone to DateTimeZone

Tags: java, jodatime

I am experimenting to Joda time.

```
    final String string_from_3rd_party = "GMT+08:00";
    // Works for standard Java TimeZone!
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone(string_from_3rd_party));
    // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id is not recognised: GMT+08:00
    System.out.println(DateTimeZone.forID(string_from_3rd_party));
```

How can I retain the `string_from_3rd_party`, yet, able to construct a Joda `DateTimeZone` out from it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the Java TimeZone to create the DateTimeZone:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(string_from_3rd_party);
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timeZone);
```

Comment: this is not taking into account daylight savings if you have a TimeZone with daylight savings configured